# Reverse Geocoding in Oracle Apex (From draggable marker)

Tags: javascript, google-maps, plsql, oracle-apex, reverse-geocoding

I currently enabled user to put the address into text-boxes and display the address on Google map, but I want to do the opposite now and get nearest matching address to the text-boxes (which are on a separate region, same page) from a draggable marker. I heard that I should use JSON with PHP or PL/JSON to get the data from the map to the text-boxes. However, I do not have any knowledge about JSON and I think Google map API provide this sort of geocoding methods inside the JavaScript. I am not sure how to fully apply it, and if it is possible to get both methods in one page (or maybe I should use some procedure with JavaScript and call it on the page, not sure). Here is my code so far in the HTML Header of the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var uniLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng (51.887496, -2.088788);
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var map;

function geocodePosition(pos) {
        geocoder.geocode({
                latLng: pos
        },
        function(responses) {
                if (responses && responses.length > 0) {
                        updateMarkerAddress(responses[0].formatted_address);
                }
                else {
                    updateMarkerAddress('Cannot determine address at this location.');
                }
        });
}

function updateMarkerStatus(str) {
        document.getElementById('P15_ADDRESS').value;
}

function initialize() {
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 16,
                center: uniLatLng,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
};

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
            flat: false,
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(59.327383, 18.06747)
})

function map_canvas() {
        var address = "&P15_ADDRESS.";
        geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address, 'region': "GB"}, function(results, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                map: map,
                                draggable: true,
                                animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                                flat: false,
                                position: results[0].geometry.location
                        });
                }
                else {
                        alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
                }
        });
}
</script>
```

Page HTML Body Attribute - onload="initialize(), map_canvas()"

Any suggestions how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I think this example does what you want on the Reverse Geocoding part.
 https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-reverse

the only thing you need to add to this is a draggable marker with a listener for `on dragged`, which would update the position and call the same methods as it is in the `Reverse Geocode` button.

Comment: Yeah I agree, however it is not as simple in apex I roughly can do it using html and JavaScript but passing the values from Google map to specific text fields (P20_ADDRESS, P20_POST_CODE etc.) on apex region requires more that that. Currently I'm doing procedure (SQL + JavaScript)  which will be called by (PL/SQL and bit of JavaScript) in order to display the marker and pass the values to a variables and variables will be converted to the specific text fields (PL/SQL). That's my plan will see how will it work ;)